# Python Pandas merge two data frames based on multiple values field

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two Pandas' data frames

```
df1
       items        view
0      A|B|C  02-10-2015
1        D|E  02-15-2015

df2
  item  num  val
0    A    1   10
1    B    3    2
2    C    8    9
3    D    9   13
4    E    2   22
```

I want to mere these frames to get

```
df 
  view       num1 val1 num2 val2 num3 val3
0 02-10-2015 1    10   3    2    8    9
1 02-15-2015 9    13   2    22   na   na
```

My current approach is to split `df1.items` using

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1['items'].str.split('|').tolist())
```

which results in

```
    0    1    2
0   A    B    C
1   D    E None
```

and finally merges each individual column and concatenates them with the original df1

```
x = pd.merge(df3[[0]], df2, how='left', on='item')
y = pd.merge(df3[[1]], df2, how='left', on='item')
z = pd.merge(df3[[2]], df2, how='left', on='item')
pd.concat([df1, x.ix[:,1:],y.ix[:,1:],z.ix[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

The code works but it doesn't seem right to me, I would be happy if anyone can point out a proper way to achieve the same results.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: `str.split` has a `return_type` argument:

```
In [11]: res = df1['items'].str.split("|", return_type='frame')

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
   0  1    2
0  A  B    C
1  D  E  NaN

In [13]: res.index = df1['view']

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
            0  1    2
view
02-10-2015  A  B    C
02-15-2015  D  E  NaN
```

I think a nicer, more general way, to do this is using stack/unstack:

```
In [15]: res = res.stack()

In [16]: res
Out[16]:
view
02-10-2015  0    A
            1    B
            2    C
02-15-2015  0    D
            1    E
dtype: object
```

Now you can either merge, or if you're lucky just switch out the index:

```
In [17]: df2 = df2.set_index('item') # could just drop this column

In [18]: df2.loc[res]  # reorder, may not be required
Out[18]:
      num  val
item
A       1   10
B       3    2
C       8    9
D       9   13
E       2   22
```

Now the magic:

```
In [21]: df2.index = r.index

In [22]: df2
Out[22]:
              num  val
view
02-10-2015 0    1   10
           1    3    2
           2    8    9
02-15-2015 0    9   13
           1    2   22

In [23]: df2.unstack()
Out[23]:
           num        val
             0  1   2   0   1   2
view
02-10-2015   1  3   8  10   2   9
02-15-2015   9  2 NaN  13  22 NaN
```

*As desired (with a MultiIndex columns, which is what you want).*

---

Note: If you have duplicates (A, B, Cs) you're going to need to merge (which is a little fiddlier, but could be cleaned up). Before [21]:

```
In [31]: df2.merge(res.to_frame(), left_index=True, right_on=0).unstack()
Out[31]:
           num        val          0
             0  1   2   0   1   2  0  1    2
view
02-10-2015   1  3   8  10   2   9  A  B    C
02-15-2015   9  2 NaN  13  22 NaN  D  E  NaN
```